# Updating javascript array variable through javascript ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript variable that holds an array to update a map and I am trying to get AJAX to update that variable with the server data so that it will update the map based on a selected option.

Basically, here is where I'm at

Javascript:

```
var mapData=[];
    function stateData(inputData){
      data = [inputData];
      return data;
    }
```

AJAX:

```
    function updateData(selectedVar){
      var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      newRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            serverdata = this.responseText;
            mapData = serverdata;
            stateData(mapData);
        }
      };
      newRequest.open("GET", "testscript.php?selection="+selectedVar, true);
      newRequest.send();
    }
```

If it helps the data that I'm transferring is in this format after PHP script:

{state="AK", hourlypay=18.22, annualpay="43,666"}, {state="AZ", hourlypay=25.88, annualpay="89,980"}, etc.

Comment: you call stateDate, it returns, but you do nothing with that?

Comment: @epascarello that function is called later to update the main map with the array of objects.  I didn't place all that on here because it's extremely long.  So it returns it into the states themselves on the interactive map with the information.

Comment: @epascarello or did you mean in the ajax?  I may have forgotten to place the main function after the stateData call in the question.  But after loading the main function, it's almost as if the data never passed through and updated the variable before the main function was called.

Comment: `mapData = [serverdata];` also seems wrong

Comment: @epascarello made some edits.  Still working on it from this end